# How I can find a best match on string records that use * as a wildcard?

Tags: sqlite3

In my application that I am making, I have the following table

```
records
------
id PK
pattern TEXT
```

In this database I have records like this

| id | pattern |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | https://*.google.com |
| 2 | https://google.com/* |
| 3 | https://go*g*.com |

And I want to match the string against the pattern. In pattern column the * is used as a wildcard character similarly used in file paths.

In my case, I want to find the best match in the for `https://google.com/lorem_ipsum`. How I can do that?

In my case I want the * to be treated as wildcard character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, the wildcard symbol that works like `*` in file paths is `%`.  You need to replace the former with the latter for the pattern to work.  You can use the `REPLACE()` function to do the substitution, then you can use the resulting string as a pattern in the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  records
WHERE
  'https://google.com/lorem_ipsum' LIKE REPLACE(pattern, '*', '%')
;
```

Output:

| id | pattern |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | https://google.com/* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5k7Vur5c?hide=6)